# How can we install Unetbootin on elementary 6.1?

Tags: usb, iso

Can `unetbootin` be installed via the terminal?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel Ninos, thank you for contributing to the community. If any existing answer was helpful, please mark it as 'answer'. If you have solved it on your own, with different method, then please add that as answer and mark it so other's can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. You will need to add a third-party repository first, though. Here's how you can do it:

0. Open the terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Add the `gezakovacs` repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
   ```
2. Update `apt` to retrieve the full list of packages and updates:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install `unetbootin`:

   ```
   sudo apt install unetbootin
   ```

That's all there is to it

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found           ?????????????????

Comment: If the `add-apt-repository` package is not already on your system, you'll need to first use `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`. This will ensure you have everything you need to add repositories to your installation 

Comment: Thanks.  unetbootin installed

Comment: If this answer helped, please click the little check mark on the left so that other people with the same question will see that it solved your problem 